# Copying dynamic range in for-each loop

Tags: vba, excel, foreach, copy-paste

I've spent the past couple weeks trying to piece together a solid piece of VBA from other suggestions in order to complete this task, but now I'm turning to you all for an answer.  I'm trying to copy a range from ws2, columns A:K of the row which starts with the value c that matches the value i in ws1 into the row which starts with the value i in ws1. The criteria being copied are 1s and 0s. It's basically a glorified looped v-lookup that pastes a dynamic range.

I figured out the looping mechanism, now I just need help composing the code for copying the selected cells over.

Here's what I have so far:

```
For Each i In ws1.Range("A4:A26")
    For Each c In ws2.Range("A8:A28")
        If i.Cells.Value <> c.Cells.Value Then
            'select columns A:K in the row with the value c in ws2
            'open ws1
            'paste selection to[starting at] column D in ws1
            Exit For

        End If
    Next c
Next i
```

Comment: You need to specify what you are trying to achieve with this code ? copy cells from which worksheet to where ? what is the criteria ? it's impossible to guess what you are trying to do without information, just a code which is not working

Comment: Please do not put code in the comments.  all further explanations should be put in the original question using [edit]

Comment: Hi Shai, I'm trying to copy a range from ws2, columns A:K of the row which starts with the value c that matches the value i in ws1 into the row which starts with the value i in ws1. The criteria being copied are 1s and 0s. It's basically a glorified looped v-lookup. Let me know if you need additional information.

Comment: Hi Scott, Thanks for the edit and your patience! I'm new here, so I haven't quite gotten the swing of formatting yet.

Comment: Won't this be true for most in sheet 1? If i.Cells.Value <> c.Cells.Value Then.  you wrote that want a match, not a non-match. "the value c that matches the value i"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want the matches, and once a match is found, then Exit the For.
This does it with out activating or selecting

```
     For Each i In ws1.Range("A4:A26")
         For Each c In ws2.Range("A8:A28")
             If i.Value = c.Value Then
                 'select the row, columns A:K that starts with the value c in ws2
                 ws2.Range("A" & c.Row & ":K" & c.Row).Copy ws1.Range("A" & i.Row)
                 Exit For
             End If
         Next c 
     Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you're aiming for. If you can clarify what you mean by "select the row, columns A:K that starts with the value c in ws1" that might be helpful. I'm assuming the `Exit For` is if the values don't match, that you want to go to the next `i` after doing everything in the `If` statement.

It might be helpful to use the Record Macro feature.

```
For Each i In ws1.Range("A4:A26")
    For Each c In ws2.Range("A8:A28")
        If i.Cells.Value <> c.Cells.Value Then
            'select the row, columns A:K that starts with the value c in ws2
            ws2.Range(Cells(c.Cells.Value, "A"), Cells(c.Cells.Value, "K")).Copy
            'open ws1
            ws1.Activate
            'paste selection, starting from column D in ws1, into ws1
            ws1.Cells(i.Cells.Value, "D").Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
            Exit For
        End If
    Next c
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Please use `ws1.Range(Cells(c, "A"), Cells(c, "K")).Copy` in likeu of `ws1.Range(Cells(c, "A"), Cells(c, "K")).Select`, `Selection.Copy`.

Comment: I'm getting a type mismatch for your ws1.Range line of code, not sure if (c, "A") will work as a naming convention because c already has a row and column position.

Comment: Please try `c.Cells.Value` instead of `c` (see edit)

Answer (score 0):

When comparing values in 2 columns in 2 worksheets you have `Application.Match` function. Instead of having two `For` loops, which are time consuming, you can have one `For` and use `Application.Match` instead of the other one.

Also, ***Copy >> Paste*** is a 1-line command, there is no need to `Select` or `Activate` anything.

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub CompareColumns()

Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet

Dim MatchRng As Range, C As Range
Dim MatchRow As Long

Set ws1 = Worksheets("Sheet1") ' change "Sheet1" to your sheet's name
Set ws2 = Worksheets("Sheet2") ' change "Sheet2" to your sheet's name

' set the matched range
Set MatchRng = ws1.Range("A4:A26")

With ws2
    For Each C In .Range("A8:A28")
        ' use Match to see if there's a match
        If Not IsError(Application.Match(C.Value, MatchRng, 0)) Then
            MatchRow = Application.Match(C.Value, MatchRng, 0) + MatchRng.Row - 1 ' get the row of the match (add 4 since the range starts at row 4)

            ' copy >> paste is a 1-line command
            .Range(.Cells(C.Row, "A"), .Cells(C.Row, "K")).Copy Destination:=ws1.Range("D" & MatchRow)
        End If
    Next C
End With

End Sub
```